# Node | error middleware doesn't handle exceptions

Tags: node.js, typescript

Our back-end application is based on node and TS, and we are using overnightJS library.
Unfortunately when I'm trying to create and Error middleware, using both:

```
 this.app.use((error:Error, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        console.log("error captured ");
        next(error);
    });
```

or:

```
@ClassErrorMiddleware(logErrorAndStop)
```

but when I throw an error in my controller:

```
@Get("table")
private async getAssetsForTable(req: UserRequest, res: Response) {
    throw Error("table error");
}
```

I expected that the error will be caught at one of the middlewares, but instead the thread is stacked on the error:

```
2021-03-14T15:09:20.060Z error: unhandled error Error: table error
```

and the server doesn't return any response (the client is waiting, probably until a timeout).

I also tried something like this:

```
 this.app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        try {
            console.log("middleware test");
            next();
        }catch (ex){
            next(ex);
        }

    });
```

the "middleware test" string was printed for each request, but then the thread was still stucked as mentioned before.

any ideas why?

Comment: I think that the "error handler" shouldn't call `next`

Answer (score 0):

Unhandled rejections are not handled by express middleware.

For e.g

```js
import express from 'express'

const app = express();

app.use(someBeforeHookMiddleware) // Middleware that are called before entering into the routes

app.get('/test1', (req, res, next) => {
  throw new Error('Hello Unhandled') // This kind of error are Unhandled and can't be caught by Express Middleware
});

app.get('/test2', (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const raiseSomeError = someErrorCausingFunction();

    if(!raiseSomeError) next() // if no error in the above function simply pass to next handler without args to next()
  } catch(error) {
    next(error) // passing error here so Error middleware is activated in the chain
  }
});


// Error handling middleware
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
 console.log('Oops !!, Error occured in req->res cycle ', error.message);
 res.status(err.status).json({ error }); // Send back Error to the Frontend
})
```